# get status of activity in view just by activity object

Tags: java, android, android-activity, view

i'm trying to write a android library that need to access to activity status, but i have not access too activity class and just access to activity object.

in my library i need to have a timer that request a content from my server ! i want to stop that timer when activity paused and resume that when activity resumed.

my class will create in onCreate method in activity and don't want to add any method in onPause or onResumed method of activity.

```
Magnet mgView = new Magnet(this, rLayout, "7c29e05ca6164c06b82c1b4ba5876231");
        mgView.LoadAd();
```

is tried these methods :

```
((Activity) context).isFinishing());
((Activity) context).isDestroyed());
```

answer of these method always was false !!!!!

is there any solution for solve my problem ?

Comment: `onDestroy()` and `onResume()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are triggering these methods ??
Instead of getting activity status, use onpause() or onstop() to stop the timer and onresume() to start the timer.
case 2 : create one global variable and set it in onpause() and onResume()
depends on this variable value start time and stop timer.

Comment: i have not access to activity . i just have activity object that pass to my class by parametr